# Binary crossentropy output, how to read the output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, deep-learning

I have a binary cross entropy model two classes: [normal, bullish]. 
When i call model.predict() the output returns a single probability, how do i know to which class the probability belongs to? 
I use a keras Functional model.

```
final layer: 1 unit, sigmoid activation.
classes: ["normal", "bullish"]
class indices: {'bullish': 0, 'normal': 1}
```

So when a single prediction returns `[0.5905021]` does it have 59% chance of being the bullish or the normal class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define a threshold which is often `0.5`. Values below threshold means it is classified as the class you specified in labels with `0`, and values above threshold means the other class.

So in your case, `0.59` means it belongs to the class you have specified as `1` which is `normal`.

Comment: Thanks! And when i have a categorical cross entropy model softmax activation with class indices `{'bearish_1': 0, 'bullish_1': 1, 'normal': 2}`. Does this then also mean that a probability distribution at index `0` is for `bearish_1` and at index `1` is for `bullish_1` and index `2` is for `normal`?

Comment: @dbergh2 : Exactly. If you have 1 separate neuron for each class and a softmax activation function, the sum of output values will be 1.0. Each output value shows the probability of it's corresponding class as output like what you said.